# Emacs: use hyperlinks to objects opening in other applications?

Tags: windows-7, emacs, hyperlink, org-mode

We have a CRM software which allows to store URLs as shortcuts to later access an object (customer, order, query, ...) again with one click.

I'm working with `GNU Emacs 24.2.1`.

From within `MS Office 2007`, those hyperlinks work directly: after clicking on it, I get a security warning and then choosing "Yes", the CRM application opens and the linked item is opened.

From within `Firefox` this works in a similar way: a dialog pops up which lets me choose the application to open the link with.

In `Emacs org-mode` however, this does *not* work: when clicking on the link I get the message
**"No match. Create this as a new heading? y n"**

How can I configure Emacs to open this link with the right application?

The link looks like:
ifscrm://client?action=find&key1=CUST1234567^Z7000225A34&table=vmo_SearchContact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a custom link type (See the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html))

It will be something similar to (you may need to adjust it slightly, depending on how the application accepts links):

```
(org-add-link-type "ifscrm" 'org-ifscrm-open)

(defcustom org-ifscrm-command "/path/to/application")

(defun org-ifscrm-open (path)
  (call-process org-ifscrm-command path))
```

Replacing `/path/to/application` as appropriate.